# SOAP Webservice Client in Java

Tags: java, web-services, soap, webservice-client

I am newbie in SOAP webservice client and getting errors while creating client.

please help me to solve this

```
//This is request that has to be send using SOAP Envelope

POST /DISWebService/DISWebService.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.2.119
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <LoginSystem xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <username>string</username>
      <password>string</password>
    </LoginSystem>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

---

## Java Code

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        // Create SOAP Connection
    SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory      .newInstance();
    SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory
                    .createConnection();

            String url = "http://192.168.2.119/VISWebService/VISWebService.asmx";
            // String url =
            // "http://192.168.2.119/DISWebService/DISWebService.asmx?op=LoginSystem";

            SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(),url);

            // Process the SOAP Response
            printSOAPResponse(soapResponse);

            soapConnection.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err
                    .println("Error occurred while sending SOAP Request to Server");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

private static SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest() throws Exception {
        MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
        SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();


        String serverURI = "http://192.168.2.119/DISWebService/DISWebService.asmx";

        // SOAP Envelope
        SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();

        // SOAP Body
        SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();

        SOAPElement soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement("LoginSystem");

        SOAPElement soapBodyElem1 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("username");
        soapBodyElem1.addTextNode("Chirendu");

        SOAPElement soapBodyElem2 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("password");
        soapBodyElem2.addTextNode("verve12*");

        MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
        headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", serverURI );

        soapMessage.saveChanges();

        /* Print the request message */
        System.out.print("Request SOAP Message = ");
        soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);
        System.out.println();

        return soapMessage;
    }
```

Please help me to create client.

Comment: `soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(),url);` this will make a SOAP request to specified URL. For what purpose you need the client?

Comment: I want to consume given webservice and need respone to show in UI

Comment: If I understand it correctly your Web Service client perfectly works and you're asking for a GUI, correct?

Comment: no webservice is not working properly and while making request it is giving me error

Comment: then please show the error (stacktrace)...

Comment: Response SOAP Message = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode><faultstring>Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: http://192.168.2.119/VISWebService/VISWebService.asmx.</faultstring><detail/></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>

Comment: Instead of posting it in a comment, please update your question!

Comment: what should I update ? neccesary things I have given

Comment: Just edit / modify the question instead of posting a comment (`edit` button at the end of the question, below the tags).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will suggest debugging in 2 steps

1)Use [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) and check whether your response in coming or not

2)Use the working example i used from [mykong](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-soap-handler-in-client-side/)

Comment: using SOAPUI for beginner would be easy to learn by comparing SOAP request